# How to plot each second column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I want to plot every second column of a pandas dataframe. The dataframe is created with two for loops. The outer loop goes through the .xls files in a directory and the inner loop goes through each sheet of a single excel table. Then these data are written in the dataframe likes this:

X1 Y1 Z1 Y2 Z2 Y3 Z3 ....

where the numbers represent the corresponding sheet of the .xls-file.

Now I want to plot all Y-data against the x-column.
The code below shows how I can plot Y1 against X1.

Before in an older version of this code all Y-data had the same name which was "Y". This makes the plotting very easy, because I just needed to say y='Y' and each corresponding column was plotted automatically. But this has the drawback that the legend is not as I would like it to be, because every label for every single plot is the same, namely "Y". But I want different labels in the legend, namely "Y1" etc. This is why I renamed the columns which leads to the problem of plotting each second column starting by column 1.

So, the question is how to plot each second column of a pandas dataframe.

Thank you in advance,
Zwieback

In general it could be quiet easy assuming I know how many Y-data I have. But unfortunately there is a different amount of sheets in each .xls-file.
Otherwise
        df.plot(x=0,y=[1,3,5], ax=ax1)
could work if there are three columns with Y-data.

```
if index %2 ==0:
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)
    ax1.set_title(str(files_xls[parameter]), fontsize = 10)
    ax1.set_ylabel('I [$\mu$A]')
    ax1.set_xlabel('E [V/m]')
    df.plot(x=0,y=1, ax=ax1)
    plt.show()
if index %2 ==1:
    ax2.set_title(str(files_xls[parameter]), fontsize = 10)
    ax2.set_ylabel('I [$\mu$A]')
    df.plot(x=0, y=1, ax=ax2, legend=True).get_figure().savefig(str(files_xls[parameter])+'.png', dpi=450)
    plt.show()             
    plt.close(fig)
```

Then I have tried to plot it with slicing.
df.plot(x=0,y=[:, 1::2], ax=ax1)
But then an error appears: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Answer (score 1):

You can set `X` as index and plot:

```
df.set_index('X1').iloc[::2].plot()
```

Another way, without `set_index`:

```
Ycols = df.filter(like='Y').columns
df.plot(x='X1', y=Ycols)
```